# Using shape as button for macro to hide/unhide rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following to hide and unhide some rows, but I want to use a shape - "RectangleRoundedCorners9" - instead of the ugly button.  The script works great on a button (does exactly what I want it to) but only on an actual button.

I don't know VBA and am not sure how to get this code to work with that shape instead of a button:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
Dim xAddress As String
xAddress = "F:G"
If ToggleButton1.Value Then
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = True
Else
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

I tried replacing as follows but get a 424 "Object not found" error on the IF line:

```
Private Sub RectangleRoundedCorners9_Click()
Dim xAddress As String
xAddress = "F:G"
If RectangleRoundedCorners9.Value Then
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = True
Else
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

BONUS:  I'd like to inject the final product into the following to get the shape to visual behave like a button as well:

```
Sub SimulateButtonClick()
Dim vTopType As Variant
Dim iTopInset As Integer
Dim iTopDepth As Integer


    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        vTopType = .BevelTopType
        iTopInset = .BevelTopInset
        iTopDepth = .BevelTopDepth
    End With


    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = msoBevelSoftRound
        .BevelTopInset = 12
        .BevelTopDepth = 4
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = vTopType
        .BevelTopInset = iTopInset
        .BevelTopDepth = iTopDepth
    End With

'---------------
'HIDE/UNHIDE SCRIPT HERE
'---------------
End Sub
```

Comment: Add the shape then right-click >> assign macro and select the code you want to run.  What exactly is the "visual behavior" you're trying to replicate?

Comment: To your first point:  The code above applies to "ToggleButton1" as if I just created a new button.  If I try to assign that to a shape as a macro, I get a 424 error - "no object found".  I get that same 424 "no object found" error when I try to replace that button with the name of my shape (probably because buttons and shapes are not the same to VBA).

And that larger second part is making the button look like it's being pressed when clicked.

Comment: The visual feedback isn't worth the trouble, or a least wont behave like normal because you don't have mouse down/up events required.  It feeds off of just the click event.  You could add `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))` to pause the visual state for up to 1s, but it's still not great.  Also, make sure that all the shape names are 30 characters or less; that seams to be the limit for `Application.Caller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub ToggleCols()

    Const RNG As String = "F:G"
    Dim s, tr

    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    Set tr = s.TextFrame2.TextRange

    ActiveSheet.Columns(RNG).Hidden = (tr.Text = "Hide")
    tr.Text = IIf(tr.Text = "Hide", "Show", "Hide")

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great and the dynamic text is a nice add-on. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Question: I want duplicate this a macro a few times for different ranges/buttons but am unsure how to do that.  Any thoughts?  I appreciate you.

Comment: Answered my own question.  Copy paste the code into two lines with the first "Sub" line having a unique name - i.e. "ToggleCols2()"